# "Ещё" в смысле "уже"

Tags: перевод

What is an English equivalent of the phrase *Ещё Аристотель отмечал, что...* , т.е. *ещё* в смысле *уже*? One might say *Already Aristotle observed that...*, but its meaning seems to be slightly different (?). Anyway, is there any other locution with roughly the same meaning?

It appears that my variant [is not idiomatic enough.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/174011/already-aristotle-observed-that?noredirect=1#comment347052_174011)

Comment: "As soon as" or "already"?

Comment: as soon as тут вообще не при чем, конструкция с already тоже неправильная - см.ссылку в теле вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Mayhap

> Even Aristotle was one who observed

or there's a need to construct the sentence differently

> The fact that.... had already been observed by Aristotle

Comment: Не, это не совсем то, что требуется - второй вариант просто переводит мою конструкцию из актива в пассив, смысл тот же. А первый вообще имеет другой смысл ( и Аристотель тоже) и хромает в смысле идиоматичности - in my opinion, either "Aristotle was **the** one who observed" or just "Even Aristotle observed that...", but both have got quite different meanings.

Comment: i could be wrong but i don't think ***already*** goes with nouns, that's why in order to use it properly, that is with a verb in this case, the construction needs a change... ***Already Aristotle observed*** doesn't sound English to me, it sounds Russian... neither my 1st attempt does sound unidiomatic to me... but anyhow, i tried

Comment: You are right—the passive goes while the active as I put it doesn't.

Comment: Очень хороший второй вариант с past perfect passive.

Answer (score 1):

> *Back in his days*, Aristotle pointed out that...

(or stronger: as early as his days, as long ago as his days)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the nearest sense of Еще Аристотель is

> Aristotle was the first to observe that...

Можно сделать более общий смысл

> As far back as Aristotle's time it was observed...

Or simply

> Aristotle,at his time, observed...